# Different email heading based on shipping methods in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications, shipping-method

So I want to send the same email with a slightly different heading in WooCommerce. It uses the argument `$email_heading` variable to hold the value of that current email heading so I figure a simple replacement would work. It doesn't. I could be completely missing the mark here any help is much appreciated.

I want it to say Your Order is ready for pickup when they choose local pickup and then the default value (stored the email settings of woocommerce) when any other shipping is chosen.

```
add_filter( "woocommerce_email_heading_customer_completed_order", 'HDM_woocommerce_email_header', 10, 2 );
function HDM_woocommerce_email_header( $email_heading, $email ) {
  if ('customer_completed_order' == $email->id && $order->has_shipping_method('local_pickup') ){
      $order_id = $order->get_id();
      $email_heading = '<h1>Your Order Is Ready For Pickup</h1>';
    }
      return $email_heading;
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code like `$email` that is in fact `$order`. Also you are already targeting `customer_completed_order` in this composite hook, so you don't need it in your `IF` statement…

So try instead:

```
add_filter( "woocommerce_email_heading_customer_completed_order", 'custom_email_heading', 10, 2 );
function custom_email_heading( $email_heading, $order ) {
    if ( $order->has_shipping_method('local_pickup') ){
        $email_heading = '<h1>Your Order Is Ready For Pickup</h1>';
    }
    return $email_heading;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Oooh you seriously are the best! Thank you so much i was working on that for way too long.

Answer (score 0):

i'm wondering if this is valid for email subject:

```
add_filter( "woocommerce_email_subject_customer_completed_order", 'custom_email_subject', 10, 2 );
function custom_email_subject( $subject, $order ) {
    if ( $order->has_shipping_method('local_pickup') ){
        $subject = 'Your Order Is Ready For Pickup';
}
return $subject;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).